# Performing left join along with where condition

Tags: sql, oracle

I was using this query to get results,

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM TRXN_REPORT CNT, 
    TBL_CUSTINFO CUSTADDINFO, 
    TBL_DEAL_EVT EVENT, 
    TBL_MISCADDR CIFMISC       
    WHERE CNT.INTERNAL_REF_NUM = EVENT.INTERNAL_REF_NUM 
    AND CNT.BRANCH = EVENT.BRANCH 
    AND CNT.QFXVERSION = EVENT.QFXVERSION 
    AND CNT.VALUEDATE = EVENT.VALUEDATE 
    AND CNT.LIQ_STATUS = 'L' 
    AND EVENT.EVENTCODE = 'LLIQ' -- Liquidation Event 
    AND CUSTADDINFO.CUSTOMER_NO = CNT.CUST_NUM 
    AND CIFMISC.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = CNT.CUST_NUM 
    AND CUSTADDINFO.REC_STATUS       ='O' 
    AND CIFMISC.REC_STATUS       = 'O' 
    AND MY_PBG_CUSTOMER = 'Y' 
    AND (BUYCCYCODE = 'USD' OR SELLCCYCODE ='USD')
```

here this condition

> AND CIFMISC.CUSTOMER_NUMBER = CNT.CUST_NUM

Is fetching only those records which are present both in `TBL_MISCADDR` and `TRXN_REPORT` table, now as a change of requirment I want to perform left outer join so as to get records which are not there in `TBL_MISCADDR` table but present in `TRXN_BATCHREPORT_WRK`. How to perform this along with maintaining all the where conditions.

Comment: You should start using the explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of the implicit (and very old) joins in the `where` clause

Comment: where is the left join?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks for guiding me in right direction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to you specify the condition for the join in the `ON` clause of the `JOIN`. So, your current conditions in the WHERE clause should be separated into the conditions for joining the tables (and these moved to `ON` clause), and the rest for selecting the lines - and these should be left in the `WHERE` clause. Example (don't know if I have it correct according to your data but you will get the idea):

```
SELECT * 
FROM TRXN_REPORT CNT 
LEFT JOIN TBL_DEAL_EVT EVENT ON 
        CNT.INTERNAL_REF_NUM = EVENT.INTERNAL_REF_NUM 
    AND CNT.BRANCH = EVENT.BRANCH 
    AND CNT.QFXVERSION = EVENT.QFXVERSION 
    AND CNT.VALUEDATE = EVENT.VALUEDATE
LEFT JOIN SOME_OTHER_TABLE T ON
...
WHERE 
    AND CUSTADDINFO.REC_STATUS       ='O' 
    AND CIFMISC.REC_STATUS       = 'O' 
    AND MY_PBG_CUSTOMER = 'Y' 
    AND (BUYCCYCODE = 'USD' OR SELLCCYCODE ='USD') 
....
```

This way you can safely use `LEFT JOIN` and the lines for which the records doesn't exist in the other table will also be included.

> ... to get records which are not there in `TBL_MISCADDR` table but
>   present in `TRXN_BATCHREPORT_WRK`.

That would be done using `TRXN_BATCHREPORT_WRK LEFT JOIN TBL_MISCADDR ON <condition>`.